# how to permanently disable ubuntu updates & hide install updates button pic included

Tags: updates

how to permanently disable ubuntu updates pop up & hide or remove **Install Updates** button pic included **see below:**

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: [Why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) do you want to do this? I doubt it will be possible without changing the source code and recompiling, and I can't imagine the use case.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the update notifier, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that doing so won't keep your system updated with security and other important updates.

To disable updates, in terminal do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
```

When it opens change the "1" to "0" as shown in the image below, and

[image]

Then change the Automatically Check for Updates to "Never" as shown in the image below.

[image]

<sup>Source for the last part complements of Guillermo G.</sup>