# Stop Update-Notifier from Loading Up

Tags: update-manager

Everytime my Ubuntu 13.04 system loads up, update-notifier opens with a list if software that can be updated. I do not want update-notifier to open. I have checked its settings and the cron and at tables for my account. Oddly, nothing is seen that would make update-notifier to come up. How can I make it stop checking for updates and not execute?

Comment: See if my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309634/how-to-permanently-disable-ubuntu-updates-hide-install-updates-button-pic-incl/309648#309648), helps.

Comment: @Mitch, your answer on the above link is interesting, but that line already has a zero instead of a one. There is nothing else in the at table and nothing at all in the cron tables.

Comment: Did you try the first command to disable the notifier?  The second one is to disable updates.

Comment: @Mitch, that command worked! Enter that comment as the answer so I can mark it. Thank you.

Comment: I can't since it'll be a duplicate answer.

Comment: @Mitch, thank you. I marked my question as a duplicate.